# How to share a single database connection across multiple phpunit integration tests?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, phpunit

Phpunit (v9.3) seems to instantiate new entity manager services and opening new database connections every time a request is fired through `KernelBrowser`. I want to keep an open, persistent database connection from the beginning of all test executions till everything has run. Sometimes database connections are not closed fast enough, thus getting us run out of resources and the tests unexpectedly stop with `mysql has gone away`.

stack: php 7.3 / symfony 5.2 / phpunit 9.3 / mariadb 10.3

Comment: Hello, I face the same problem, have you found a solution for this? :)

Comment: I can't remember if we fixed this, but the `processIsolation` setting in phpunit.xml lessened the symptoms